# Bind method on Silex

Tags: php, routes, silex

I couldn't find it anywhere. So I ask: On silex, why do we use bind() for? For example, on this routing of static pages:

```
$pages = array(
    '/'      => 'index',
    '/blog'  => 'blog',
    '/about' => 'about',
);

foreach($pages as $route => $view) {
    $api->get($route, function(Silex\Application $app) use($view) {
        return $app['twig']->render($view.'.html');
    })->bind($view);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For an event-heavy framework, it's a bit of a poor choice, but this basically names the route.

Things like providers can get access to the routes if they are given a name.

Relevant documentation:

- http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#named-routes

Comment: Thanks. That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

From [the silex documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#named-routes):

> Some providers (such as `UrlGeneratorProvider`) can make use of named routes. By default Silex will generate a route name for you, that cannot really be used. You can give a route a name by calling bind on the Controller object that is returned by the routing methods:

```
$app->get('/', function () {
    ...
})->bind('homepage');

$app->get('/blog/{id}', function ($id) {
    ...
})->bind('blog_post');
```

> It only makes sense to name routes if you use providers that make use of the `RouteCollection`.